# MySQL callback after alter table

Tags: mysql, triggers, procedure

There is some solution in MySQL for detect changes in first table (`ALTER TABLE`) for to have an identical copy of the second table structure (no data).

I would like copy the columns, column default values and types.

Some `PROCEDURE`, `TRIGGER` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, MySQL does not support DDL triggers.

Workaround here might be enabling general logging to a table, then using external scheduled(?) script to select DDL queries you are interested in and do whatever you want based on that information